# Getting AddressAlreadyInUseException after upgrading to .NET 4.5

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, configuration, .net-4.5

I recently installed the new .NET Framework 4.5 (previously was 4.0 installed) on my Server and I´m getting a `System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException` when I start my Windows Service that exposes WCF endpoints.

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a
>   listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:56543. This could happen if there is
>   another application already listening on this endpoint or if you have
>   multiple service endpoints in your service host with the same IP
>   endpoint but with incompatible binding configurations. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket
>   address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionListener.Listen()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ExclusiveTcpTransportManager.OnOpen()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener
>   channelListener)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback
>   selectTransportManagerCallback)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpChannelListener`2.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at Qosit.Infrastructure.UnisServer.OnStart(String[] args)

The configuration of my WCF endpoints looks like that:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MEX">
          <serviceMetadata/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MEX" name="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.MyService">      
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:56543/MyService"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingConfiguration" contract="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.MyServiceInterface" />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:56543/MEX" binding="mexTcpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I think it has something to do with the MEX endpoint that uses the same port, but I'm not sure how to configure it correctly after upgrading to .NET Framework 4.5.

Was there a change in WCF so that these configuration raises an exception?

Comment: I'd check the TCP usage with something like [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to see what may already be using that port. Also, try changing to another port and see if you still have the same problem. Finally, [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/08/23/713297.aspx) has some good information on MEX with `netTcpBinding`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because of some limitations in using the same port for both the netTcp endpoint and mex endpoint documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702636.aspx) refer section "Sharing a port between a service endpoint and a mex endpoint using the NetTcpBinding". In 4.0 the defaults for `listenBackLog` and `MaxConnections` were 10. In 4.5 these defaults were revised as 12 * ProcessorCount. This exception happens when you try to share a port between netTcpBinding and mex endpoint provided you have different values for these two properties. In 4.0 this worked fine as you have set these to the default values (10) and thus these settings do not differ on both endpoints. But in 4.5 these are left as 10 for netTcp endpoint, but computed as 12* ProcessorCount. So the exception.

To solve this issue there are 2 ways:

1. Remove these settings (`listenBackLog` and `MaxConnections`) from the config. In this way you will get a default of 12 * Processor count automatically which is > than 4.0 defaults.
2. Follow the work around of configuring mex endpoint on a different port as described in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702636.aspx)

Please check out [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2012/10/16/nettcpbinding-amp-mextcpbinding-sharing-same-port-throws-addressalreadyinuseexception-on-upgrade-to-net-4-5.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Choosing Option 1 did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you host a WCF service in a console application you need to copy the App.config file from the WCF project to the console app and then delete the App.config file from the WCF project,if you don't you can also get the above error.